# Android daily updating geofences

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-geofence

I'm working on creating a coupon/deals app. The premise is that each day there will be special deals at different stores. When a user happens to be close to a store (within a geofence), I'd like to send a notification to the user of the coupon/deals at that store.

Given that the stores may change daily, I'm trying to figure out the best way to update the Geofences.

One idea - use AlarmManager to create an alarm that would trigger at like 12 am each day that sends an intent that starts a service that queries my server > pulls the list of new Geofences > sets those new Geofences.

Is that reasonable? Is there a better way to handle it?

Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right path, check [CommonWare's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) [Repository](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/)

Comment: Oh yea, this seems like exactly what I was looking for - I didn't even think of the booting piece either :)

Comment: If you want to toss that in an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path, check [CommonWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) [Repository](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/)

It doesn't keep the device on wake up and only to do the service call.